# Confusion about the existence of the antiderivative of this function in this domain.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$. Let $\Omega$ be the domain of complex numbers such that $\mathrm{Re}(z)>2$. It's clear that $f$ is continuous on $\Omega$. We can also write $f$ as:

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{z}=\frac{z^*}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}-i\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$$

Then you can show that the Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied if $x^2+y^2 \neq0$ which is true $\forall z\in \Omega$. Therefore, using the [Looman-Menchoff theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Looman%E2%80%93Menchoff_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20the%20mathematical%20field%20of,satisfies%20the%20Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann%20equations.), $f$ is holomorphic over $\Omega$. Since $\Omega$ is a simply connected domain, Cauchy's Theorem should apply and therefore $\oint f=0$. This is also the necessary and sufficient condition for the existence of an antiderivative on $\Omega$. So $f$ must have an antiderivative.

However, $\mathrm{Re}(z)>2$ includes number such as $z=3$ which fall on $\mathbb{R}^+$, but that's where the branch cut of $\mathrm{Log}(z)$ is and it's generally the reason as to why $1/z$ does not have an antiderivative in $\mathbb{C} -[0]$.

What's going on? What am I missing? (Also, I apologize for any writing mistakes. English is not my first language. I don't always know when to use "on $\Omega$", "over $\Omega$", etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need Looman-Menchoff; $f$ is holomorphic since it's the reciprocal of an obviously holomorphic function which doesn't vanish on $\Bbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ (so in particular $\Omega$ as well). Next, there are several branches of $\log$ one can define. For example, $\log:\Bbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,0]\to\Bbb{C}$, with the branch of argument such that $-\pi<\text{arg}(z)<\pi$, is holomorphic, and its derivative is $\log'(z)=\frac{1}{z}$. So, $f$ has a primitive not only on $\Omega$, but also on a much larger open set.

Comment: Oh, so I guess you could define a piece-wise function including the antiderivative for $\mathbb{C}$ excluding $\mathbb{R}+$ whenever you are in $\mathbb{R}-$ (for example), and the opposite for the antiderivative excluding negative reals.

The problem would be writing one single antiderivative, right?

Comment: @agaminon I'm not sure I understand. This isn't a piecewise definition. Logarithms can be defined holomorphically in the complement of any half-ray emanating from the origin. For example, if I wanted to, I could have removed the upper-half of the imaginary axis, and I'd still get a perfectly good logarithm, which is an antiderivative of $f$ on $\Omega$.

Comment: My point is that any logarithm you choose is going to exclude some branch cut. For example, the logarithm for the branch cut $0<\mathrm{arg}(z)<2 \pi$ is only an antiderivative for $\mathbb{C}-\mathbb{R}^+$.

My thinking is that you could define the antiderivative of $f$ piecewise. For any non-positive real, it's just the logarithm previously mentioned. For positive reals, it's some other logarithm with another branch cut.

Comment: @agaminon right, but necessarily we have to exclude something. In your case, you're working in $\Omega$, so I excluded the non-positive real axis in my answer.

Comment: I assume this is a problem of my textbook's theorems not being clear enough. In my textbook, the "necessary and sufficient condition for the existence of an antiderivative in $\Omega$" is path independence (equivalently, that $\oint f=0$). However I assumed this meant that there would be an antiderivative for *all* $\Omega$. I suppose this is not the case?

Comment: @agaminon the theorem is true as stated. It just happens that $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ with domain $\Bbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ doesn't satisfy the condition. If you restrict to $\Bbb{C}$ minus a half-ray, then it is simply connected so the sufficiency condition is satisfied, so $f$ has a holomorphic primitive.

Comment: But $f$ is regular and $\Omega$ (though not necessarily $\mathbb{C}-0$) is simply connected, meaning Cauchy's theorem should hold and $\oint f=0$. Then the condition holds. So what am I missing?

Comment: idk what you're missing. I'm saying that $f$ does have a primitive on $\Omega$, and I gave you explicitly a branch of logarithm which works. THis is in complete agreement with the theorem.

Comment: Oh, sorry! I confused the branch cut for $-\pi<\mathrm{arg}(z)<\pi$ with the one for $0<\mathrm{arg}(z)<2 \pi$. With the first one it absolutely is an antiderivative for the entirety of $\Omega$.